# Visual Studio solution properties: Debug|Mixed Platforms.ActiveCfg = Debug|.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I'm looking in the .sln file of some old code, and I see various lines that end with `Debug|.NET`. **<- What does this '.NET' mean?** (as opposed to 'any cpu' or 'x86')?
Full line:
`{F9E9F25D-1008-4098-A4A7-179A0512F745}.Debug|Mixed Platforms.ActiveCfg = Debug|.NET`
Examples can be seen here (line 56):
https://github.com/apereo/dotnet-cas-client/blob/master/DotNetCasClient.sln

These settings can be found in the gui (Solution Explorer -> right click on the solution -> Properties -> Configuration Properties) - and if I change them from ".NET" to "Any CPU" they get stuck there and .NET is no longer an option. (Visual Studio 2008, targeting .net 3.5)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part to the right can be named anything the person writing the project wants. It is the "Platform Configuration name" and is fully customize-able in the GUI. You just need to choose `<New>` from the "Active Solution Platform" drop-down (This is how it is in Visual Studio 2013, that is the earliest version I have installed).

As to why you can't change it back and it disappearing, it is because the only place it is used is the project with the id `{F9E9F25D-1008-4098-A4A7-179A0512F745}`. If you look higher up in the file that ID is for `ExampleWebSite`, that site does not have a project file and instead is defined inside of the `.sln`. In the section for the site no build config named `.NET` is defined, so once you change it off it can't be changed back because there is nothing to change it back to because it is a invalid build configuration.

My recommendation, use `DotNetCasClient.vs2010.sln` instead, it is more recently checked in  and does not have invalid build configurations.